# SQL Server Profiler 2017 - Logging Select 1

Tags: sql-server, profiling

I am profiling my Azure SQL Server database and the profiler is logging too many `SELECT 1` queries. However, no actual user or app is making the query and I don't remember seeing it in before. Is there any problem? Is this a known issue?

[image: Image of profiling]

Comment: Did you check login name / host of the process that sends it to your server?

Comment: This is likely the health check inside of Azure, making sure your database is alive and working.